# STM8S001J3 not responding

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, stm8

[image]

I am using an STM8S001J3 in a project as shown in the above circuit.

I am trying to program it using the below code using IAR and programming it using STVP. STVP gives successful message, but the microcontroller doesn't respond. There is no output on any of the 3 pins. Can someone please check what am I doing wrong here?

```
   #include <iostm8s001j3.h>
    
    #define SIGNAL_PIN PD_IDR_IDR6
    #define LED1_PIN PB_ODR_ODR4
    #define LED2_PIN PC_ODR_ODR5
    #define TRIGGER_PIN PB_ODR_ODR5
    
    void main(void) {
        // Set Pin 1 (PD6) as input with pull-down, Pin 4 (PB4) and Pin 5 (PC5) as outputs
        PD_DDR_DDR6 = 0; // PD6 as input
        PD_CR1_C16 = 1; // Pull-down input
        PD_CR2_C26 = 0; // Disable interrupt
        PB_DDR_DDR4 = 1; // PB4 as output
        PB_CR1_C14 = 1; // Push-pull output
        PC_DDR_DDR5 = 1; // PC5 as output
        PC_CR1_C15 = 1; // Push-pull output
        PB_DDR_DDR5 = 1; // PB5 as output
        PB_CR1_C15 = 1; // Push-pull output
    
        while (1) {
            // Check the state of SIGNAL_PIN and set TRIGGER_PIN, LED1_PIN, and LED2_PIN accordingly
            TRIGGER_PIN = 1;
            LED1_PIN = 1;
            LED2_PIN = 1;
        }
    }
```